# React useState updating value is causing it to flicker back to original value

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to display a fraction that gets larger and larger by a small amount every second. But it is flicker back to its initial value (either 0 or null, either way). I want it to smoothly update without flickering. I could do it in vanilla JS, but I thought react hooks should work...?

```
  useEffect(() => {... SET INITIAL VALUE FOR FRACTION TO NULL }

  function increaseFraction() {
    const increase = 1 + avgInflationRate/secondsInAMonth;
    setFraction(fraction * increase)
  }
  setInterval(increaseFraction, 1000);
```

Comment: Can you please provide a [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to debug it?

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to understand where your code is failing but seems that you are not using interval correctly.

The entire example below is referenced from Dan Abramov's article: [Making setInterval Declarative](https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/)

Another concepts to read more are: [State as a snapshot](https://react.dev/learn/state-as-a-snapshot) and [Guide to useEffect](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/)

First of all, your intervals should be declared within useEffect. Why? because on each render React removes the useEffect and mounts a fresh one, which means it forgets what was declared previously. But things like setInterval should be cleared manually, React wont clear it for us. So in useEffect you can declare a return method that clears it.

Initial solution will be something like this:

```
const [fraction, setFraction] = useState(1);

useEffect(() => {
  function increaseFraction() {
    const increase = 1 + 7 / secondsInAMonth;
    setFraction(fraction * increase);
  }
  const interval = setInterval(increaseFraction, 1000);

  return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, []);
```

However, this still won't work. Why? Because the function `increaseFraction` will always reference the fraction value that it found during the declaration let say 1. So everytime the function runs, it will look something like this

```
function increaseFraction() {
  const increase = 1 + 7 / secondsInAMonth;
  setFraction(1 * increase);
}
```

In order to make `increaseFraction` reference to latest value we take help of useRef. The final solution will look something like below.

```js
const {useState, useRef, useEffect} = React;

const secondsInAMonth = 60 * 60 * 24 * 30;

const App = () => {
  const [fraction, setFraction] = useState(1);

  const ref = useRef();

  const callback = () => {
    const increase = 1 + 7 / secondsInAMonth;
    setFraction(fraction * increase);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = callback;
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    function increaseFraction() {
      ref.current();
    }
    const interval = setInterval(increaseFraction, 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  return <div>{fraction}</div>;
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById("root")
).render(
    <App />
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```